# JQuery Auto Read More and Read Less issue

Tags: jquery, click, nested, append

I am trying to create an Auto read more and read less where you just pop in a `<a href="#" class="readmore">YOUR TEXT"</a>` anywhere in your text and have run into an issue. Right now it almost works but if you open up a couple of different readmores then hit the readless all the readlesses on the page close. Any ideas? All the code is below with comments.

```
// Auto Readmore with a link that has the readmore class
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Show Read more link that is hidden by css
    $('.readmore').show("fast");
    // Loop through all  .readmores
    $('a.readmore').each(function(index) {
        // Set the Node of the link
        var currentreadmore = $(this);
        // set the id to the index of the each
        $(this).attr('id', 'readmore-' + index);
        var node = currentreadmore[0];
        if (node && node.nextSibling) {
            // if not at the end of a paragraph remove the rest of the paragraph and append ...
            var afternodecontent = node.nextSibling.nodeValue;
            node.nextSibling.nodeValue = " ...";
        }
        // hide everything after the readmore link
        $(this).parent().nextAll().hide();

        // create click function to append the rest of the paragraph and show the content. Also hides the readmore button
        $(this).click(function() {
            // add the content back in
            if (node && node.nextSibling) node.nextSibling.nodeValue = afternodecontent;
            // hide the content
            $(this).parent().nextAll().slideToggle("slow");
            // hide the read more button
            $(this).hide("slow");

            // add the readless button
            $(this).parent().nextAll().last().append('<p id="readless-' + index + '" class="readless-wrapper"><a href="#" class="readless">Read Less...</a></p>');    

            // hvea the readless button click work
            $('.readless').click(function() {
                // show the readmore info based off of the index of the button
                $('#readmore-' + index).parent().nextAll().slideToggle("slow");

                // show the read more
                $('#readmore-' + index).show("slow");

                // append the ... and hide the rest of the content
                if (node && node.nextSibling) {
                    // if not at the end of a paragraph remove the rest of the paragraph and append ...
                    var afternodecontent = node.nextSibling.nodeValue;
                    node.nextSibling.nodeValue = " ...";
                }

                // remove the readless button
                $('.readless-wrapper').remove();

                // stop the href
                return (false);
            });
            // stop the href from working
            return (false);

        }); // Close Click function
    }); // Close Each Function
}); // Close document ready
```

Comment: Can you post some example HTML that shows the problem?

Comment: And, maybe, a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here you go:http://jsfiddle.net/bUcZ3/ as you can see it works fine if we have one readmore link in there. But if you have two then open the both up it gets very confused.